# Unable to access WSO2 EMM store and publisher via reverse proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 on a server but I want the requests to the server to flow through another server which has the reverse proxy entries being managed on nginx.

I am able to access the carbon management console, but not able to access the store or publisher.

The store or publisher sites redirect to /samlsso and /sso/login which are local redirects. I am not able to find the location of these redirects and how they can be modified.

Please help!

Comment: I see that the same flow is followed for WSO2 Enterprise Store. Hope the solution for this would help with fixing the Enterprise store issue as well.

Comment: try configuring sso-idp-config.xml with your reverse proxy values

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 was released with WSO2 Carbon 4.2.0 kernel. Hence you won't be able to use [this method](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon430/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path). Please use the configuration files given below and modify the "**identityProviderURL**" property to configure the location of SSO application.

1. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/1.1.0/modules/apps/emm/config/config.json
2. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/1.1.0/modules/apps/publisher/config/publisher.json
3. https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/1.1.0/modules/apps/store/config/store.json

Regards,

Harshan

Answer (score 0):

you can configure reverse proxy on any wso2 product by following documentation [Adding a Custom Proxy Path](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon430/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path)

Comment: Thanks Lakshman! I went through the page. It has a message saying "this functionality is only available for WSO2 product versions that are based on the Carbon 4.3.0 platform." But the WSO2 Product release matrix shows that the Enterprise Store using Carbon 4.2.0..so not sure if this solution will work..I will give it a try.